# curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.8 port 80: Connection refused

Tags: curl, docker, kubernetes

I am new to Docker and Google Kubernetes technologies. I was following the following tutorial video which is focused on setting up Kubernetes and using a single node Kubernetes cluster. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DC7NECq3Ghs

In this tutorial, there is a point where I create three replicas of nginx pods and when I curl the pod with IP address 172.17.0.8, I get the following connection issue.

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.8 port 80: Connection refused
```

I checked some of the solutions provided for previous queries about this issue and tried the following command, but I am still without any success.

```
curl --ipv4 172.17.0.8
```

The other two pod IP addresses work successfully, with curl.

I would be grateful for any help to this issue with explanations and bear with me for any mistakes when posing this question since I am extremely fresh to Google Kubernetes, Docker and networking clustering concepts.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: No Kamran, I fixed it.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to this thread. This can help other users, who may face the same issue, resolve their problems.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a firewall issue: on GKE you had to open the port 80 on the node in order to access it.

Now since a few weeks, port 80 is opened automatically when you create a Service setup with type LoadBalancer.

On another provider, you may still need to open the port.